# Jquery Select Box. How to make it appear on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So my website is cutting of my select boxes. Is there a way to make the select box pop out of the frame of the popup (view attached). this method is preferred  --- not to interested in making my popup bigger and or containing it within a smaller frame.

[image]

Comment: increase z-index to box..quick fix

Answer (score 0):

Increase z-index on box and `overflow: visible`